# How to perform bicubic upsampling of image using pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pytorch

I have png image. I want to upsample it using bicubic interpolation. I found this function in pytorch:

```
nn.functional.upsample(mode = "bicubic)
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html

But how to apply to my png image? Should I turn my image into some torch tesnor? I just haven't found any example of using this function exactly on png image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
import torch 
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image


t = transforms.ToTensor()
img = Image.open("Table.png")

b = torch.nn.functional.upsample(t(img).unsqueeze(0),(500,400),mode = "bicubic")
```

you can also apply Bicubic using Image

```
img = Image.open("Table.png")
re = img.resize((400, 400),Image.BICUBIC)
```